# Creating an empty field on discord embed field but horizontal gap is too big, discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I used these two methods to create an empty 3rd field on discord because I plan to just have 2 fields per row:

- Method #1: `{ name: '\u200b', value: '\u200b' }`
- Method #2: `{ name: '** **', value: "** **"}`

But both of these are showing a huge gap on embed similar to the image shown on the official embed documentation: [Discord Embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview), or like this, [Huge gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BHyr.png)

Is there a way to make the horizontal gap smaller like these?
[Sample 1](https://miro.medium.com/max/363/1*Kun0bDlls58ejUPK0ywT_Q.png), [Sample 2](https://baronbot.github.io/command_examples/profile.png)

Comment: well, if you want a littler gap just add `\u200b` to the name of the field and write in the value of that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update. There is no way around this. This is how discord display its fields on an embed.